# Updating multiple objects in an Array belonging to a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mern

I'm using **MERN** stack for my program with mongoose for accessing the database. I have a collection called Movies and I wanted to edit multiple objects in an array within this collection. This is what the Movie Schema contains in my database:

[image]

I wanted to edit multiple objects in the 2D array within **seats** and to change **isReserved** to *True*.

I just used **findOne** in accessing the data since I still don't know how to update the objects that I want to access.

```html
app.post('/confirm/:movieId/:timeId', (req, res) => { 
    const movieId = req.params.movieId;
    const timeId = req.params.timeId;
    const selectedSeats = req.body;
    // console.log("in confirm DB ");
    // console.log(selectedSeats);
    let getSeats;
    let getTimeSlots;
    const length_timeId = timeId.length;
    Movies.findOne({ movieId }, (err, movie) => {
        console.log("INSIDE");
        getTimeSlots = movie['timeslots'];
        let index = timeId.substring(1, length_timeId);

        //get the seats
        getSeats = getTimeSlots[parseInt(index)-1];
        //loop through seats 
        console.log("PRINTING GET SEATS");
        console.log(getSeats);
        for(var i=0; i<selectedSeats.length; i++) { 
            let row = parseInt(selectedSeats[i] / 5);
            let id = selectedSeats[i] % 5;
            console.log(getSeats["seats"][row][id]);
        }
    })
})
```

I already accessed the objects that I want to edit as that code displays this on my terminal:
[image]

Would really appreciate some tips on how to update the isReserved status. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots. Use formatted text also for sample input and output data, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266

Comment: Storing date, time or duration as **text** is a design flaw, you should never do that. Store always proper `Date` objects, for durations I suggest to store number of Seconds (or Minutes, depending on your requirements)

Answer (score 0):

Do you specify the timeslot and seat by an `id` or by the index within the array? If you use the index then solution is quite simple

```
const key = "timeslots." + req.params.timeId + ".seats." + req.body + ".isReserved";
var upd = {};
upd[key] = true;

db.Movies.updateOne({ movieId: req.params.movieId }, { $set: upd })
```

If your code uses the `id` then you have to work with array filters, see [Update Nested Arrays in Conjunction with $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#std-label-position-nested-arrays-filtered), so similar to this

```
db.Movies.updateOne(
   { movieId: req.params.movieId },
   { $set: { "timeslots.$[slot].seats.$[seat].isReserved": true } },
   { arrayFilters: [ { "slot.id": req.params.timeId } , { "seat.id": req.body } ] }
)
```

Comment: Do I use updateOne or updateMany? Would just like to note that i wanted to update multiple objects within the array. So it would still work?

Comment: `updateOne()` means you update one document - no matter how many objects you update within this document.